# JSON parsing in android using inbuilt json library?

Tags: android, json

How to parse this JSON in Android???

```
{
    "From": "13-06-2014",
    "To": "19-06-2014",
    "Employee": [
        {
            "EmpId": "1",
            "EmpCode": "101",
            "EmpName": "abc",                
            "EmpLName": "def",
            "Job": [
                {
                    "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "EmpId": "1",
            "EmpCode": "101",
            "EmpName": "abc",                
            "EmpLName": "def",
            "Job": [
                {
                    "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                },
                {
                     "ID": "1",
                    "JobName": "abc",
                    "Time": "12:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can parse it with inbuilt json library. show what you've tried so far.

Comment: have you even tried anything... see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);` -- you can start from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
   String jsonRespone="{\"From\":\"13-06-2014\",\"To\":\"19-06-2014\",\"Employee\":[{\"EmpId\":\"1\",\"EmpCode\":\"101\",\"EmpName\":\"abc\",\"EmpLName\":\"def\",\"Job\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"}]},{\"EmpId\":\"1\",\"EmpCode\":\"101\",\"EmpName\":\"abc\",\"EmpLName\":\"def\",\"Job\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"JobName\":\"abc\",\"Time\":\"12:00\"}]}]}";

   JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(jsonRespone);
   String From = responeJson.getString("From");
   String To = responeJson.getString("To");

   ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

   JSONArray employeeJsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("Employee");
   for (int i=0;i<employeeJsonArray.length();i++){
        HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("EmpId",employeeJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EmpId"));
        row.put("EmpCode",employeeJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EmpCode"));
        row.put("EmpName",employeeJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EmpName"));
        row.put("EmpLName",employeeJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EmpLName"));

        JSONArray jobJsonArray = employeeJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Job");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int j=0; j<jobJsonArray.length(); j++){
            HashMap<String,String> job = new HashMap<String, String>();
            job.put("ID",jobJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("ID"));
            job.put("JobName",jobJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("JobName"));
            job.put("Time",jobJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Time"));
            jobList.add(job);
        }
        row.put("Job",jobList);
        data.add(row);
   }

   System.out.print("From : "+From);
   System.out.print("To : "+To);

   for (HashMap<String,Object> row :data){
       System.out.print("EmpId : "+row.get("EmpId").toString());
       System.out.print("EmpCode : "+row.get("EmpCode").toString());
       System.out.print("EmpName : "+row.get("EmpName").toString());
       System.out.print("EmpLName : "+row.get("EmpLName").toString());

       ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jobs = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) row.get("Job");
       for (HashMap<String,String> job :jobs){
           System.out.print("ID : "+job.get("ID"));
           System.out.print("JobName : "+job.get("JobName"));
           System.out.print("Time : "+job.get("Time"));
       }
   }
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an easy to understand example for encoding and parsing json:

[Android JSON Tutorial: Create and Parse JSON data](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html)

and

[JSON in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)